# Non sequential (un-ordered) data for neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I'm looking for how to input non sequential (un-ordered) data into neural network.
For example, I want to cluster 2 classes with the following samples.

- sample 1-1: A, B, C, D
- sample 1-2: A, C, D (B may be lacked)
- sample 1-3: D, A, C, B (the order can be changed)
- sample 2-1: X, Y, Z

sample 1-1, 1-2, 1-3 should be in a same cluster even if they are a little different each other.
sample 1-? and 2-1 should be in different clusters.

I tried to sum them all (like A+B+C+D compared with A+C+D) to make it fixed size but it was no good.
Do you have good idea?

Comment: Unordered means that there is no possibility to sort this inputs in any order?

Comment: Right, no way to sort them. And possibly some of the data like B in 1-2 is lacked so sorted data cannot be input into neural network because the input size is not fixed.

Comment: So how can you sum it? What sort of data is it.

Comment: A, B, C are n-dimensions float32 values. These are fixed.

Comment: Dude but you are able to sort them e.g. in lexicographic order.

Comment: What have you actually tried? It should be able to work for any given order _if you train it to work that way_. Try before asking!